# How to retrieve multiple datas from SQL to VBA textbox?

Tags: sql, vba

I've a code like this:

```
SQL = "SELECT STA_ID, AVG(STA_INCOME) " & _
      "FROM STAFF " & _
      "WHERE STAFF_EXP = '" & Label1.Value & "' " & _
      "GROUP BY STA_ID"
rs.Open SQL, cn

With rs
i = 0
    Do Until .EOF
       label2.Value = rs(1)
       label3.Value = rs(0)
       i = i + 1
       .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```

I can retrieve the average `STA_INCOME` in label 2, but I can only retrieve one instead of multiple `STU_ID` data in label 3. What can I do to let the text box (label 3) show multiple values if it matches the `Label1.Value` that I typed in? Many Thanks.

Comment: But you also have multiple averages for each ID as well. You loop code keeps reassigning labels to finally show the *last* of each. How do you want text box to show multiple IDs? Line or comma separated?

Comment: You may have to create the labels (or any other control like text box), dynamically

Comment: Or you can  concatenate each value from rs, with a new line  character during the loop, and finally assign that to a multi-line text box.

Comment: @Srinika What do you mean by concentration each value?

Comment: @kerz, That is like what is done in the answer given by Parfait below.

str_ids = str_ids & rs.Fields(0).Value & vbNewLine

Answer (score 0):

Consider concatenating all IDs and averages from recordset loop to populate text boxes:

```vb
' RETRIEVING SINGLE AVERAGE
avg_SQL = "SELECT AVG(STA_INCOME) " & _
          "FROM STAFF " & _
          "WHERE STAFF_EXP = '" & Label1.Value & "' "
rs.Open avg_SQL, cn
label2.Value = rs.Fields(0).Value
rs.Close


' RETRIEVING MULTIPLE IDs
id_SQL = "SELECT STA_ID" & _
         "FROM STAFF " & _
         "WHERE STAFF_EXP = '" & Label1.Value & "' " & _
         "GROUP BY STA_ID"
rs.Open SQL, cn

' ITERATIVELY CONCATENATE VALUES
str_ids = ""
Do Until rs.EOF
   str_ids = str_ids & rs.Fields(0).Value & vbNewLine
   rs.MoveNext
Loop

label3.Value = str_ids
rs.Close
```

Comment: i is not serving any purpose

Comment: @Srinika, I kept that `i` in since OP has it in code. Possibly it is used later on.

Comment: @Parfait Thanks. But I would like to show the average of ' STA_INCOME ' for all data selected. ' str_avgs ' will have shown all ' STA_INCOME ' instead of the average. What can we do to show the average?

Comment: You need to run two different queries. One with and without `GROUP BY` (latter only including `AVG(STA_INCOME)` in `SELECT` ).

Comment: @Parfait The 2 queries should be in the same sub statement?

Comment: See edit running two separate recordset queries to assign to your *label2* and *label3* values.